Algorithm to find minimum parameter value for which the function reaches a height
I have a continuous function $f:(0,1]\times (0,1]\to [0,1]$ satisfying the following properties:

For every fixed $b$, $a\mapsto f(a,b)$ is strictly increasing.
For every fixed $a$, $b\mapsto f(a,b)$ has a unique maximum

I want to have a practical algorithm that efficiently computes
$$a_*(c) = \inf\{a\in(0,1]:\sup_{b\in(0,1]}f(a,b)\geq c\}$$for any $c\in[0,1]$.
In words, we fix a threshold $c$, and then find the smallest $a$ for which $f(a,b)\geq c$ for some $b$.
I want to compute $a_*(c)$ efficiently given any $c$. Is this problem classical? Is there a well known algorithm / solution for this that provably converges to $a_*(c)$?
Here is what I came up with:

Start with a grid $G=\{(a_i,b_j):1\leq i,j\leq n\}$ such that $a_i<a_j,b_i<b_j$ for every $i<j$.
Take $a'$ to be the smallest $a$ for which there exists a $b$ such that $(a,b)\in G$ and $f(a,b)\geq c$.
For this $a'$, choose the $b'$ for which $f(a',b')$ is minimal among $f(a',b)$ for all $b$ (thus far computed).
Update $G$ to be a finer grid surrounding $(a',b')$ and repeat.

I am afraid it misses some edge cases, e.g. what happens when the smallest $a$ or $b$ appears along the edge? Do we expand our grid $G$ before we decide on $a_*$ or $b_*$? I feel like this algorithm works as long as $(a_*,b_*)$ are interior points in the grids under consideration, which makes me unsure about the edge cases.
I feel like getting $a_*(c)$ must be a classical approach, as it shares similarities with minimax procedures and so on, so I believe there is a provable algorithm out there. I just don't know how to find it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
EDIT: A possible solution is to take a grid of $(a,b)$ values, then for each $a$ apply Brent's method to compute the maximum of $b\mapsto f(a,b)$, and thus for each $a$ decide if there is a $b$ achieving $c$. Then apply a bisection method to find $a_*(c)$. However, this algorithm does not take into account the joint continuity of $f$ in $(a,b)$ which should ideally simplify things.

if f(a,b) continuous? What about continuous first derivatives and hessian? Do you know the formula for f(a,b) or is it unknown?

Nothing is known except that I can query $f$ at points $(a,b)$ and that $f$ is continuous (as mentioned in the question).
